# Android Custom Camera Quality

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using the following parameters for my custom camera

```
mCamera = getCameraInstance();

params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
params.setExposureCompensation(0);
params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
params.setJpegQuality(100);
params.setRotation(90);

List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

And after a photo is taken, the quality of the image is quite bad. I have autofocus and flash in use.

This is my method for taking the photo..

```
mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mgr.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        }
    };

    PictureCallback pictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data,
                Camera camera) {
            ...
        }
    };

    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback,
                null, null, pictureCallback);
    }
});
```

It is especially bad when the flash doesn't fire (I'm using auto flash) and the room I'm in is well lit..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use `getSupportedPictureSizes()`, it doesn't necessarily return them in any order. It's probably returning a horrible size in `sizes.get(0)`. You should compare them to find the biggest size if you want the best quality. Something like:

```
List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
{
    if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
        size = sizes.get(i);
}
params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
```

Comment: Well, the size is consistent now, but I'm still seeing quite jagged edges on the images.. does this have something to do with fitting the image to the screen because the final image, once saved is just fine..

Comment: Probably something similar with the preview size. Try messing with `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` for that. Try to find the one that most closely matches the aspect/size of your preview window.