# Android Camera Image Quality Very Low

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to capture an image from camera but the image quality is really bad. I don't know why as I am a newbie to coding for android.

I have tried a couple of things but didn't worked out. Here is my code. Please help me where to change the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextureView1 = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView1);

        mTextureView1.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(getCameraId());
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
             Camera.Parameters params=mCamera.getParameters();

        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
        {
            if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
                size = sizes.get(i);
        }
        params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
     params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
        params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
        params.setExposureCompensation(0);
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        params.setJpegQuality(100);
        params.setRotation(90);

        params.setJpegQuality(100);
        params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(getCameraId(), cameraInfo);
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, getCameraId(), mCamera);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                                   int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }


    private int getCameraId() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
               // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }


    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int mediaTypeImage) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }
}
```

[image]

Which is way lower than 13 megapixel camera in my phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Custom Camera Quality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606705/android-custom-camera-quality)

Comment: No, the answer does not help, already tried that one.

Comment: This may not be directly applicable to yours, but when I made a VIDEO CAMERA, I made the profile of the MediaRecorder object as `mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));`  EDIT: This might be really only for video. so nevermind. You can go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605560/how-do-you-take-high-resolution-images-using-camera-takepicture) to check out similar question/answer

Comment: I am already doing that what is given in the link, and yeah, what you are telling does not apply to me as I am not making Video Camera.

Comment: Specifics regarding what you've already tried should be [included in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32528743/edit).

Comment: I am facing same issue... Have you found any solution?

Comment: @seema did you set the parameter `params.setJpegQuality(100);` and `mCamera.setParameters(params);` after setting parameters?

Comment: Same problem but cant find any solution anywhere on web. Were you able to solve?